# How to get maximum reliability and least delay from sensors

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors

One listener for 3 sensors (Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Heart-Rate) or 3 separate listeners for all sensors?

This is how I'm registering the sensors:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
    acc_sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    heart_sensor= sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
```

This is my current approach towards getting the values:

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {

        }
else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

        }
else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE) {

        }
```

The problem is that the amount of values obtained over a period of time are inconsistent. The sampling rate of Moto-360 is 50 with the delay set to DELAY_FASTEST, like this:

```
sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, acc_sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
  sensorManager.registerListener(this,heart_sensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

The number of values given have been tested over intervals ranging from 1 second to 4 hours and the sampling rate (calculated from: values returned divided by seconds the app ran) has been varying too much.
Would using 3 seperate listeners for the SensorManager provide more consistent results?

Comment: AFAIK, you can use the `SensorEventListener` interface: [`onAccuracyChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html#onAccuracyChanged(android.hardware.Sensor,%20int)) and [`onSensorChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html#onSensorChanged(android.hardware.SensorEvent))  to get the accuracy of the sensor. Then the delay would be the one that you've already implemeneted.

Comment: That isn't the question. I've used 0 as the delay for the sensors. All three of them. The maximum and most frequent sampling rate that is produced is 50Hz but it isn't consistent. What could be the problem?

Comment: Additionally, I need a comparison between the two approaches.